# The number of independent solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Give a differential equation of order $n$ which has infinite independent solutions. Is it possible? In other words, Is the solutions space dimension of a differential equation always smaller than its order?

The example "$(y^{\prime})^2=-\vert y\vert$" is one that the dimension of its solutions space (=0) is strictly smaller than the order (=1).

Answer (score 0):

Consider $y' = 2\sqrt{|y|}$, $y(0) = 0$. For any $a \ge 0$, 
$$ y_a(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \le a \\ (x-a)^2 & x \ge a \end{cases} $$
has 
$$ y_a'(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \le a \\ 2(x-a) & x \ge a \end{cases} $$ 
and is therefore a solution. Note that $\{y_a \mid a \ge 0\}$ is a linear independent set.

Comment: Consider the linear case with constant coefficients of order $n$. Taking the Fourier transform you obtain an $n^{th}$ order algebraic equation in the Fourier variable $k$ so in this case there are at most $n$ solutions.